# Failed to load model from "MODEL PATH"

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am using the sample from
[THIS LINK](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android)

I have my own model.pb and label file

I have ended up with the error as below

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Not a valid TensorFlow Graph
>   serialization: NodeDef mentions attr 'Truncate' not in Op y:DstT; attr=SrcT:type; attr=DstT:type>; NodeDef:
>   Postprocessor/Cast_3 = CastDstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_INT32,
>   Truncate=false. (Check whether your
>   GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your
>   GraphDef-generating binary.).

Inside of my gradle I have tried both ways

```
dependencies {
    if (nativeBuildSystem == 'cmake' || nativeBuildSystem == 'none') {
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.8.0'
     //   implementation files('libs/libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar')
    }
}
```

Using Gradle and using lib, but ended up with same error.

Please assist.

PS: My server tensorflow verion is 1.14.0